# how to add a new table using EFCodeFirst to the existing database aspnetdb.mdf?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have not found information how to do the following:

how to add a new table using EFCodeFirst to the existing database aspnetdb.mdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems EFCodeFirst CTP5 is only able to create databases from scratch, and not generate tables in existing ones. :/

Comment: how about the current EFCodeFirst?

Comment: @Administrator: You should be able to use EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly to only create the tables, and not the DB. I read about it a couple of weeks ago, but I have not had the time to test it yet.